# Раскрытие условий получения секретных шляп Winter Bash 2021

Tags: обсуждение, новогодние-шляпы

*Предлагаю сообществу включиться в процесс раскрытия условий получения секретных шляп.*

Две секретных шляпы удалось расшифровать, но это было нетрудно.   Так как эти две шляпы выдают себя по названиям. Оставалось только проверить по участникам их получивших.

*1. Monologue*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предполагаю, что это шляпа- присваивается за несколько комментарий без ответа

---

*2. Dialogue*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оставлено 5 комментарий от одного человека при обмене мнениями под постом.

***Дополнительное условие*** для получения шляп: `Monologue`, `Dialogue`, - на момент получения шляпы, у участника не должно быть знака - ***Комментатор***

### Ниже нераскрытые шляпы

*3. Thought bubble*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

*4. Spotting scope*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

*5. Satellite view*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

*6. Detective*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*7. E-pic*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

***One buried penny***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предлагаю протестить шляпу "диалог". А может уже есть ответы на en so?

Comment: могу предположить, что `satellite view` за какое-то количество просмотров через "поделиться ссылкой на сообщение"

Comment: Было бы интересно добавить пару шляп, которые просто присуждаются по одной в день совершенно случайным образом — и угадывай, за что :) Хотя если назвать такую шляпу "счастливчик"... :)

Comment: На MSE ведётся [аналогичный список](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372999/339911).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Замечательно. Значит общими усилиями быстрее раскроем секретные шляпы

Comment: А One buried penny как получается? У меня она есть, интересно откуда. На аналогичном списке MSO написано "неизвестно"

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 вспомни, что делал перед шляпой. На всякий случай выборка из чата на En Meta [по этой шляпе](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=One+buried+penny&room=132350)

Answer (score 3):

#### Manual key

[image: Manual key]

> Copy something from the body of a post on a Meta site (MSE included). The question must be a discussion (из этого [поста](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372999/winter-bash-2021-hat-list/373001?newreg=ece0252d7faa47dfb80087e73454752c#373001))

У меня получилось получить это шляпу только на `meta.stackexchange.com` при копировании текста из поста с тэгом [discussion](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion), шляпу получил не сразу, после нескольких попыток и с задержкой

---

### Не разгаданные:

#### Game hat

*<картина не найдена>*

> Hat with ID -100, referenced in the wummer-hats.js source file. (из этого [поста](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372999/winter-bash-2021-hat-list/373001?newreg=ece0252d7faa47dfb80087e73454752c#373001))

Все, что у меня получилось - эта найти этот файл: [wummer-hats.js](https://cdn.sstatic.net/WinterBash/js/wummer-hats.js)

Используя `Ctrl+F`, там можно найти следующую строку:

```
const gameHatId = -100;
```

Так же есть необычный комментарий, возможно, это связанно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же возможно, что следующий кусок кода как-то связан с `Defender of the Unicorn hat`

```
... 'img/wb-unicorn-game-inbox.svg' ...
```

#### Defender of the Unicorn

[image: 5]

> 1. Post a question that later receives a status-completed tag on Meta Stack Exchange (confirmed by Yaakov)
> 2. unknown trigger

---

#### Список странных комментариев в `wummer-hats.js`

```
// modifying cached state like a boss
// fire and forget
// lyfe.js
// we should never be included in a channels page, but if we were -- right back outta here
// WinterBash.hats.addHatToGravatar([18, 31][hatPlacement.i%2], -200 + 400*Math.random(), -100 + 500*Math.random(), 50+Math.random()*100, -45 + 90*Math.random(), $gravatar, absolute, STATIC_CONTENT_ROOT)
/* BEGIN mostly copied from core's 02_TopBar.js */
```

Comment: задержка с выдачей шляпы понятна, надо же обойти столько серверов, сделать выборки из БД. Я тоже жду шляпу `Helping finger` уже несколько часов. Вроде сделал всё, как писали в чате

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выдаётся после трех заработанных  секретныx шляп на одном сайте

Для примера -  [@Артемий Шувалов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/390520/%d0%90%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%a8%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2?tab=profile)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Manual key**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шляпа прилетела после <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> => <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> ссылки на пользователя и картинку. Но до этого я копировал сообщения из чата EN.
В профиле показывает, что  шляпу я получил на англ. мете.

Очень вероятно, что шляпа именно за `copy paste` выдается.
Попробуйте и сообщите пожалуйста. Может надо сделать 5-10 разных копирований.

***Upd***

> Copy something from the body of a post on a Meta site (MSE included).
> The question must be a <kbd>discussion</kbd> ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59909909#59909909))

Скопируйте что-нибудь из тела сообщения на сайте Meta (включая MSE). Вопрос должен быть в <kbd>discussion</kbd> (обсуждении)

---

**Helping finger**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Comment on a new user's first post) x3 [confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59906256#59906256)

Прокомментируйте первый пост нового пользователя) x3  confirmed by Catija

*Уточнение:*
добавить положительный комментарий к первому вопросу 3 разных новых участников, также это относится и к первым ответам новых участников

---

***Thought Bubble***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Have a conversation in chat: at least 5 distinct blocks of messages
> [sent] in chat in one room [in] a day ([confirmed by Slate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59911779#59911779))

Общайтесь в чате: не менее 5 отдельных блоков сообщений [отправленных] в чате в одной комнате [в] день. ([подтверждено by Slate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59911779#59911779))

---

***Kitsune***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Vote to reopen a question and answer it with a positive score once it
> is reopened ([confirmed by Slate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59912467#59912467))

Проголосуйте за повторное открытие вопроса и положительно ответьте на него, как только вопрос будет открыт. ([подтвержденный by Slate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59912467#59912467))

Comment: Пытался минут 20 - ничего не вышло, возможно что-то связанное с третьей клавишей из клавиатуры (которая с логотипом). На момент получения шляпы у Вас были включены в настройках `горячие клавиши`? Вы использовали какие нибудь другие горячие клавиши? Может это так же связанно с [этим](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/)?

Comment: @Agzam Нет горячих клавиш в настройках и "это" не было подключено. Сейчас читал чат enSO на мете, там тоже как-то пишут о неоднозначности получения этой шляпы, - при копировании текста в чат. Также проблемы с шляпой защитника единорога. Модератор ответил, что условия получения шляпы оч. гибкие и меняются по ходу.  Я думаю это просто баг.

Comment: а юзерпик Detective можно и без заработанных шляп поставить. У меня есть примеров 

Comment: @Эникейщик хорошо бы привести примеры людей у кого это произошло так.  Пока имеем информацию:  ["Earn 3 secret hats on a specific site confirmed by Yaakov"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373001/440057)  Это один из модераторов, который рулит шляпами

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, спасибо, теперь у меня есть `Manual key шляпа`: Copy something from the body of a post on a Meta site (MSE included)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT так же там что то говорилось про `hats.js` и `Game hat`, я нашел этот файл: [файл](https://cdn.sstatic.net/WinterBash/js/wummer-hats.js), так же там раскопа" эту строчку: `const gameHatId = -100;` Я думаю ссылку на `hats.js` можно добавить в Ваш ответ

Comment: @Agzam Поздравляю! вы можете дать прямо здесь свой ответ и скопировать ссылку в нём. Подготовьтесь, всё проанализируйте и оформите свой ответ. Этот топик и был рассчитан на то, что мы все вместе будем искать решения

Comment: бедный @АртемийШувалов ... Его берут как пример :)))

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 ну почему бедный :) богатый, сколько людей просмотрят его профиль. Зато очень наглядно - секретную шляпу `Detective` можно получить только после получения трех секретных шляп

Comment: @Alexandr_TT да понятно) Я просто посмеялся.

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 Что-то копировал в чат или из чата?

Comment: Из :) Это, наверно, я @АртемийШувалов скопировал.

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 опять баг.. скопировал на русскую Мету, а показывает, что заработал на англ. Мете Вообще-то это очень проблемная шляпа. англ модератор пишет, что запуталась с определением символов в скрипте и ждет понедельника, (когда появится другой модератор :)) я так думаю  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374189/440057

Comment: в чате не был, шляпу Thought Bubble дали

Comment: Ааа... мне детектив не дали. хотя 3 шляпы есть

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 У вас только две секретные шляпы, для `Detective` нужно третью  получить